# Select a block of YAML with regex

Tags: php, regex, yaml

I have a big YAML file and I want to select an entire node using regex. For instance:

```
Node1:
  Child:
    GrandChild: foo
Node2:
  AnotherChild:
    AnotherGrandChild: bar
Node3:
  LastChild:
    LastGrandChild: foo
```

How can I use regex to select all of Node2 in the above example, and return:

```
Node2:
  AnotherChild:
    AnotherGrandChild: bar
```

Comment: Assume that all of the node names are completely arbitrary. In reality, I don't have the consistent pattern you see above. Node names can be anything, and can have an indeterminate number of children, grandchildren, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As everything else in that node is indented (if I understand YAML right), this does work at least at your example string:

```
$mask = '~(^%s:\n(?:^[ ].*\n?)*$)~m';
$pattern = sprintf($mask, 'Node2');
$r = preg_match($pattern, $yaml, $matches);
$node = reset($matches);
```

At least on my computer. Wanted to make a codepad demo, but it gives error. Will check the regex.

Full blown:

```
$yaml = <<<EOD
Node1:
  Child:
    GrandChild: foo
Node2:
  AnotherChild:
    AnotherGrandChild: bar
Node3:
  LastChild:
    LastGrandChild: foo
EOD;

$mask = '~
(                     # start matching group
  ^                   # a node start always at the beginning of a line 
  %s:                 # placeholder for sprintf for the nodname + :
  $                   # end of line for the nodename              
  \n
  (?:                 # non-matching group to hold all subsequent, indented lines
    ^                 # beginning of sublines
    (?:[ ]{2})+       # indentation is required, always a muliple of two spaces, non matching group
    .*\n?             # match anything else on that subsequent line, optionally the newline character
  )*                  # 0 or more subsequent, indented lines
)$                    # this ends a line, to not take over the newline of the last subsequent line (see \n? above).

# the following are modifiers:
# m - pcre multiline modifier (in php same as in perl)
# x - to allow spaces and the comments all over here ;)
~mx
';
$pattern = sprintf($mask, 'Node2');
$r = preg_match($pattern, $yaml, $matches);
$node = reset($matches);

var_dump($node);
```

Comment: Wow, that looks great. Doesn't work, but I think it has potential. The indentation is in multiples of two spaces -- no tabs..

Comment: Just curious.. would you mind walking through that for me? I've never seen regex quite that advanced, and I'm curious how you solved it.

Comment: @aaron: I put the two spaces per indent in there and added some notes. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. That's great. Never knew what a "non matching group" was. I have one last question. It seems the pattern is a little too greedy. If there is a line break between two nodes that contains no characters, only spaces, it includes that as part of the same node. Only if I have an empty line does it terminate the match in the correct place. I tried, this, but it returns empty: '~(^  %s:$\n(^([ ]{2})+[^\s]*\n?)*)$~m'Any ideas?

Comment: Well from the specs you've given, even an empty line that only contains spaces _is_ part of the node.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use a library like [php-yaml](http://code.google.com/p/php-yaml/).

Comment: Thanks. I am using that, or something like it. But I really need something to just edit the YAML text for this. I'm not really interested in parsing it so much as finding and replacing specific blocks of YAML.